# Is it possible to use QLPreviewController to generate a document preview thumbnail?

Tags: objective-c, quicklook

I do some research on `QLPreviewController`, it requires me to use the `QLPreviewController` to present a document or something like that. Is this possible for me to get the live document content as icon but within loading the `QLPreviewController`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible on iOS (yet).